# Is there a way to load a picture from memory to excel using automation?

Tags: excel, vba, ole

I know I can add a picture to an excel sheel using [Shapes.AddPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture) like this:

```
sheet.ShapesAddPicture("temp.png", msoTrue, msoTrue, x, y, w, h);
```

So I can generate a bitmap, save it to disk then load it to Excel. But, it is very slow.

I'd like to transfer the bitmap directly to Excel, without using a temporay bitmap file. Is there a way to do this using Excel automation?

Comment: Where do you want to transfer the bitmap from?

Comment: You *might* be able to build it on the clipboard and paste it, but are you sure that the file IO is your bottleneck here?

Comment: @TinMan I have a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource` object

Comment: @Comintern: saving the PNG and `LoadPicture` both take a lot of time (in my project it's more than 50% of the complete excel processing time, about 500ms, for 2 PNG's).
I thought about the clipboard, but I have not tried it yet because I do not kow how to position a paste bitmap.

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: @TinMan: C# using excel interop

Comment: @Comintern: I just tried copy/paste solution and mange to get it work. It is actually slower. Picture operation takes ~1500ms compared to 500ms.